# Raspberry Pi, and linux systemd, and .system files

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, systemd

I'm trying to to run a script when my raspberry pi reboots, but its giving me this error. the script works when I run it in terminal, but it doesn't run when I use systemd

```
● Refridgerator.service - The refridgerator thing

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Refridgerator.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-01-19 17:20:34 EST; 11min ago

  Process: 777 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Refridgerator.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 Main PID: 777 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 19 17:20:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started The refridgerator thing.

Jan 19 17:20:33 raspberrypi python3[777]: Traceback (most recent call last):

Jan 19 17:20:33 raspberrypi python3[777]:   File "/home/pi/Refridgerator.py", line 3, in <module>

Jan 19 17:20:33 raspberrypi python3[777]:     from pydub import AudioSegment

Jan 19 17:20:33 raspberrypi python3[777]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydub'

Jan 19 17:20:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Refridgerator.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Jan 19 17:20:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Refridgerator.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

```
[Unit] 
Description=The refridgerator thing 
After=multi-user.target 
[Service] 
Type=simple 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Refridgerator.py 
Restart=on-abort 
[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Can you provide systemd service file that you're using? It's probably executing service as a root, and you don't have those modules installed system wide, but rather only as pi user.

Comment: [Unit]

Description=The refridgerator thing

After=multi-user.target

[Service]

Type=simple

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Refridgerator.py

Restart=on-abort

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: im kinda new to stack overflow, and dont really know how to use it, it wouldnt let me edit the post and add more code without adding more details, so i kinda just put it in the comment, sorry!

Comment: No worries, what you can do, and in my opinion is better solution than running your service as a root, especially if you don't have to, is specifying user in your systemd service file. You can achieve this by adding `User=pi` under `[Service]` directive. For more dynamic way of doing this, you can check [systemd specifiers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers).

Comment: okay, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by reinstalling pydub with sudo pip instead of just pip

```
sudo pip3 install pydub
```

or

```
sudo pip install pydub
```